# jQuery highlight div when checkbox selected

Tags: jquery

I have a page with several sections, each with a corresponding checkbox. When a checkbox is selected, I would like to highlight the containing div (and have the color gradually fade away). When a checkbox is deselected, there shouldn't be a highlight. I have two questions: What's the best way to have jQuery highlight a div? How do I trigger the highlight on ONLY checkbox selection, not deselection?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle example?

Comment: What have you tired? Please post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point reinventing the wheel, so for the highlight effect, use http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight (which will make your life much easier).

For checking the state of the checkbox, use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), however `.is(':checked')` is also valid.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked'))
           $('div').eq($(this).parent().index()).effect("highlight", {}, 1000); 
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/gmPtY/2/

Comment: I had some trouble with this effect firing on unwanted divs, but this code worked for me: `$(this).closest('div').effect("highlight", {}, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('.parent-class').addClass('highlight');
    }
}
```